# Delete Current Author Frontend user while delete custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, users

I created custom post type using Toolset. I want to delete current post author ( front-end user ) when i delete the post.

I tried below code :

```
add_action('before_delete_post', 'my_deleted_post');
function my_deleted_post($post_id){
    global $post; 
    if ($post->post_type == "agency") {
        //echo $post->post_author;exit;
        require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/user.php' );
        wp_delete_user( intval($post->post_author) );
    }
}
```

But it is not working to me can anyone help me here ?

Comment: Where is your code saved (which file)? Why are you including `user.php`?

Comment: inside function.php

Comment: Using an action or filter hook or just as it is?

Comment: I updated my question....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `$post` will be defined where you are using it.  Try relying on the post ID that is passed to your function instead:

```
add_action('before_delete_post', 'my_deleted_post');

function my_deleted_post($post_id){ 
    if ( "agency" == get_post_type( $post_id ) ) {
        require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/user.php' );
        wp_delete_user( intval( get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id ) ) );
    }
}
```

Be aware that `wp_delete_user()` will try to delete any other posts, of any post type, owned by the same user and that might cause an infinite recursive loop.  Using the third parameter to `wp_delete_user` to reassign other posts may be a good idea.  Or simply remove your function from the hook before trying to delete the user:

```
add_action('before_delete_post', 'my_deleted_post');

function my_deleted_post($post_id){ 
    if ( "agency" == get_post_type( $post_id ) ) {
        remove_action('before_delete_post', 'my_deleted_post');
        // break unwanted recursion
        require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/user.php' );
        wp_delete_user( intval( get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id ) ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: I got ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE so it goes to infinite loop.

Comment: Removing the hooked function should fix that - question edited.

Comment: Yes it is reducing  the infinite loop... Thanks For The Help...

Comment: Cool - no problem!

Comment: Just One Editing in answer that use wp_redirect('your desire path'); so it wil not display message access denied

Comment: Ah - of course - you mean that if you are on the post edit page and delete it, then deleting the user actually deletes the post before the original delete function gets to it.  Try hooking into `deleted_post` instead, so that you delete the user after deleting the post.